# CSS Target the correct div from multiple with same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to delete a `margin-top` to a paragraph inside a div, only when the whole div has a height bigger than `138px`.

The problem is that I have multiple divs with the same class, and some of them have a height bigger than `138` and others don't.

Right now when one of them is higher than `138px`, my jQuery adds the `margin-top: 0`; to every `div.llamada > p`

How can I target only the correct `.llamada p` and not the others? My code:

HTML

```
<div class="call llamada">
    <p style="margin-top: 0px;">This is the box number one with height bigger than 138px (correct style).</p>
</div>
<div class="call llamada" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <p style="margin-top: 0px;">This is the box number two with height lower than 138px (incorrect style).</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.llamada').each(function(){
    var heightllamada = $(".llamada").outerHeight()

    if (heightllamada > 138){
      $(".llamada p").css('margin-top',0);
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your jQuery code to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.llamada').each(function(){
    var heightllamada = $(this).outerHeight()

    if (heightllamada > 138){
      $(".llamada p").css('margin-top',0);
    }
  });
});
```

What you were wrong was inside the `.each()` function when getting `heightllamada`.

Before you had `$('.llamada').outerHeight()`. This will go through each div with a class of `llamada` and get the height, then the last div height will be assigned to your variable.

I changed it to `$(this).outerHeight()`. Using `this` will get the element that is currently in the loop. You could also modify your `.each()` like so:

```
$('.llamada').each(function(index, element) {
```

And then use `$(element).outerHeight()`

**EDIT:**

You also need to change this line:

```
$(".llamada p").css('margin-top',0);
```

To this:

```
$(this).children('p').css('margin-top',0);
```

This is for the same reason as above, you need to use `this`. The `.children()` is used to select a child element (in this case the `<p>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.llamada').filter(function() {
        return $(this).outerHeight() > 138;
    }).find('p').css('margin-top', 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you A. Wolff! Your example also works. Only missing to target the <p> parragraph. Best!!